# Call matlab exe from php is not working well

Tags: php, matlab

I have compiled a matlab script into a standalone win app and also a console app. The script can be called from the command line using image_process pic1.png. The exe runs and produces a string as a result.
No I want to deploy it in php. I have added a folder to my main website directory called uploads. I need to run php to call the matlab exe to run on the images inside this folder.

Now I go to my PHP script. I define my uploads directory :

```
define("UPLOAD_DIRECTORY","./uploads"); // defines the uploads directory
```

then I add the path to my image processor:
define("IMAGE_PROCESSORE",dirname(dirname(**FILE**))."/image_process.exe");

at last I configure my process like :

```
case "process":
    $res=array();
    $pic=isset($_REQUEST["pic"])?trim($_REQUEST["pic"]):"";
    if($pic==""){
        echo "No picture name is passed";
        exit();
    }
    exec(IMAGE_PROCESSORE.' "'.realpath(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY).'" '.$pic,$res);
    //exec(IMAGE_PROCESSORE." ".$pic,$res); // this one if I define the image_process.exe inside the uploads folder
    echo"<pre>";
    print_r($res);
    echo"</pre>";
break;
```

So when I call my php like :

```
localhost/mysitename/phpresponse.php?act=process&pic=pic1.png
```

I will get no output, but If I run

```
localhost/mysitename/phpresponse.php?act=process&pic=c:\xampp\htdocs\mysitename\uploads\pic1.png
```

The matlab compiled file will run and execute

I am really confused, I did try many things but with no luck...

Comment: You should `echo` the string you are passing to exec in both cases. This should help you see what the difference is and where your desired operation is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a solution. I have made the script call 2 arguments and then instead of using exec i used passthru to execute the compiled matlab script. I don`t know why exactly it worked but at least it did :-)

Comment: In this case, edit your own answer to provide more details to the SO community, and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is related to your [Last Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778565/how-to-define-a-path-in-matlab-script/8778595#8778595) , so I will answer it here.
First of all, in a compiled Matlab **EXE**, the parameters are passed one-by-one through command line.

I would start by running the **EXE** file outside of **PHP** in command line, with the arguments that you give in a script. If it works, the problem is in the **PHP** script. If not check the Matlab code again.

Comment: I did run the matlab exe in the command line and it worked fine.

Comment: In that case, there is something wrong in the PHP. Try using a PHP debugger to see what happens (Search for "php debug" on SO)